90s movie where sheriff intimidates a guy with a coyote story
I hope there are people who know movies by stories / jokes told in them since this is about all I remember from this one. A sheriff in a desert town intimidates some guy by telling him a story about what coyote females do when they're in heat: they go into town, have a few male dogs follow them because they sense her hormones, lead them to the coyote pack that kills them. The sheriff looked like Robert Duvall / William Forsythe, as in older and balding.
I saw it in the early 2000s. I think the plot was the rather generic one where some people need to do some business with the mob, involving drugs or weapons and the sheriff was trying to intimidate a less experienced villain. I've tried googling this but with no luck, it's either not one of the more memorable quotes or simply google won't prioritize movie searches when you look for coyotes and dogs.
